# Materializecss - Tags input with Typeahead.js

Tags: typeahead.js, html-input, materialize

So I am using Materialziecss and a third-party library for tags input

1. Materializecss: http://materializecss.com/
2. Materialize Tags library: http://henrychavez.github.io/materialize-tags/examples/

Now according the documentation of the tags input library, if you are willing to include typeahead functionality for auto complete, you need to include a typeahead.js library.

The one recommended by them was http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js

I am trying to apply the library however I could not get it working.
My code is as following

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('select').material_select();
                
                $('#en_tags').materialtags({
                    typeahead: {
                        source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
                    }
                });
});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets')?>/css/materialize-tags.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets')?>/js/materialize-tags.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets')?>/js/typeahead.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="input-field">
    <label for="en_tags">English Tags</label>
    <input type="text" name="en_tags" id="en_tags" value="" data-role="materialtags"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The docs appear to have a typo.  "typeahead" should be "typeaheadjs".  Also just having an array as the source did not seem to work.  Rather, the bloodhound library worked well for me.

```
var dummyTags = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: ['dummy', 'tags', 'galore']
});
$('#tag-input').materialtags({
  typeaheadjs: {
    source: dummyTags
  }
});
```

Lastly the latest typeahead version changes the class name of an element from "tt-dropdown-menu" to "tt-menu", so the materialize styling isn't applied. You'll want to put this in a stylesheet to override the materialize picker styles.

```
.tt-menu {
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:100%;
    padding:10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.35)
}
.materialize-tags .tt-menu .tt-suggestion {
    line-height:1.1rem !important;
    padding:2px 10px !important
}
.materialize-tags .tt-menu .tt-cursor {
    background:#03a9f4;color:#fff
}
```